Running mpirun from OpenMPI does nothing, freezes as if it were waiting for network or something
I have installed openmpi 4.1.6 in kubuntu 24.04 from the repositories. The output of mpirun --version is:
mpirun (Open MPI) 4.1.6

Report bugs to http://www.open-mpi.org/community/help/


However, if I try the following command, I get nothing, no errors or messages, as it is hang on something or waiting for something, I have to Ctrl+C several times to quit. It should write hello 4 times.
mpirun -np 4 echo hello

My sshd_config file has been modified to accept only connections from a certain IP range, and I read that the issue could be related to ssh not able to connect to localhost. I made some changes to that file and now I am able to ssh localhost.
These are the changes done in my sshd_config file. Note that I have to include the last exception as if localhost was an IPv6 or it won't connect. Anyway, using the default configuration file, mpirun still does not work.
PubkeyAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
Match Address 192.167.*.*
   PubkeyAuthentication yes
   PasswordAuthentication yes
Match Address 192.168.*.*
   PubkeyAuthentication yes
   PasswordAuthentication yes
Match Address 127.0.0.1
   PubkeyAuthentication yes
   PasswordAuthentication yes
Match Address ::1
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    PasswordAuthentication yes

I am not sure how to get more information to deal with this problem, and I can't find more clues. Do you have any hint? Thank you in advance
EDIT: I just installed mpich and the following command runs well: mpirun.mpich -np 4 echo kk
EDIT 2: I compiled OpenMPI 4.1.6 from sources and the issue is still there. However, I compiled OpenMPI 5.0.4 and it works well. So it is something related to Openmpi 4.1.6. I read something about issues when the computer has several network adapters, but I tried thouse solutions without success.
